# matplotlib arrow color not work as expected

Tags: python, matplotlib

How to change the arrow color in below demo code?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def save_fig(fig,pngname):
    fig.savefig(pngname, dpi=fig.dpi, bbox_inches="tight")
    print("[[%s]]"%pngname)    
    return

def add_arrow(fig,ax,lw,lc):
    xmin,xmax = ax.get_xlim()
    ax.arrow(xmin,0,xmax-xmin+.2,0,#fc='k', ec='k',
         lw = lw,head_width=.1,head_length=0.4, overhang = 0, 
         length_includes_head=False, clip_on = False,edgecolor='k',facecolor=lc) 
    return

def main():
    x = [
    #"FLAGS",
    "INTENDED_VSYNC",
    "VSYNC",
    "OLDEST_INPUT_EVENT",
    "HANDLE_INPUT_START",
    "ANIMATION_START",
    "PERFORM_TRAVERSALS_START",
    "DRAW_START",
    "SYNC_QUEUED",
    "SYNC_START",
    "ISSUE_DRAW_COMMANDS_START",
    "SWAP_BUFFERS",
    "FRAME_COMPLETED",
   ]

    lw = 2
    lc = "grey"
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(8,.2))
    y = [0]*len(x)
    ax.plot(x,y,color=lc)

    ax.set_ylim([0,0.1])
    plt.xticks(rotation=45,ha='right')
    ax.tick_params(direction = 'inout',color=lc)
    ax.tick_params('both', length=20, width=lw, which='major')
    ax.tick_params('both', length=10, width=lw, which='minor')
    plt.yticks([], [])
    for direction in ["left", "right", "bottom", "top"]:     
        ax.spines[direction].set_visible(False)
    add_arrow(fig,ax,lw,lc)
    #save_fig(fig,sdir + "/vsync.png")
    plt.show()
    return
sdir = "/home/tester"
main()
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The color is defined in [`ax.arrow()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.arrow.html) by `color`, `edgecolor` and `facecolor`.

- `edgecolor` sets the color of the edge of the arrow.
- `facecolor` sets the color in the arrow body.
- `color` sets the color of both, `edgecolor` and `facecolor`.

If you would like to have a uniformly colored arrow, you can either set `color` to the desired value or alternatively set both, `edgecolor` and `facecolor` to the same value. In this case it would mean removing `edgecolor` and `facecolor` and adding `color=lc` or alternatively replacing `edgecolor='k'` with `edgecolor=lc`.

---

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def save_fig(fig,pngname):
    fig.savefig(pngname, dpi=fig.dpi, bbox_inches="tight")
    print("[[%s]]"%pngname)    
    return

def add_arrow(fig,ax,lw,lc):
    xmin,xmax = ax.get_xlim()
    ax.arrow(xmin,0,xmax-xmin+.2,0,#fc='k', ec='k',
         lw = lw,head_width=.1,head_length=0.4, overhang = 0, 
         length_includes_head=False, clip_on = False,color=lc) 
    return

def plot():
    x = [
    #"FLAGS",
    "INTENDED_VSYNC",
    "VSYNC",
    "OLDEST_INPUT_EVENT",
    "HANDLE_INPUT_START",
    "ANIMATION_START",
    "PERFORM_TRAVERSALS_START",
    "DRAW_START",
    "SYNC_QUEUED",
    "SYNC_START",
    "ISSUE_DRAW_COMMANDS_START",
    "SWAP_BUFFERS",
    "FRAME_COMPLETED",
   ]

    lw = 2
    lc = "grey"
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(8,.2))
    y = [0]*len(x)
    ax.plot(x,y,color=lc)

    ax.set_ylim([0,0.1])
    plt.xticks(rotation=45,ha='right')
    ax.tick_params(direction = 'inout',color=lc)
    ax.tick_params('both', length=20, width=lw, which='major')
    ax.tick_params('both', length=10, width=lw, which='minor')
    plt.yticks([], [])
    for direction in ["left", "right", "bottom", "top"]:     
        ax.spines[direction].set_visible(False)
    add_arrow(fig,ax,lw,lc)
    #save_fig(fig,sdir + "/vsync.png")
    plt.show()
    return

plot()
```

[image]